# bxSlider - move controls inside the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, bxslider

I am trying to work with bxSlider (http://bxslider.com/).

When disabling the controls (`controls:false`), the margins or padding on the left and right where the controls used to be are still here. Which means I loose a lot of precious space.

[image]

See the first image is what I get after disabling controls, and the second one is the width it was supposed to be. Not only do I waste space, but also when clicking on the next slide I see a part of the previous slide that didn't fit.

I've tried to force the width on the `<ul>` tag and on the `<li>` tag but it didn't help:

```
<ul id="slider1" width="660">
  <li width="660">
  <div class="home-slider">

                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="description">
                            <h3>La cuisine au style industriel</h3>
                            <div class="author dark">Marie Clairet Maison</div>

                            <p class="gray">
                                J'aime beaucoup le concept de self service pour la cuisine. 
                                J'ai vraiment l'impression d'être devant un e comptoir de self à la cantine. 
                                Le problème, c'est qu'il faut vraiment avoir de la place pour s'offrir ce genre d'installation.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="images/home-slider-placeholder.png" />
                    </div>

                </div>    
  </li>
  <li>Slide two content</li>
  <li>Slide three content</li>
  <li>And so on...</li>
</ul>
```

When looking at Firebug, I see that the plugin is adding a width of 626 everywhere. I didn't write this, something is generating that number:

[image]

For reference, the ultimate thing I'm trying to build it supposed to look like this:

[image]

See how I need to put the controls INSIDE the slide...

Comment: You'll want to use `position:absolute` or `position:relative` depending on how you've laid out the everything else. However, I can't provide a specific answer because you haven't provided any of your code.

Comment: updated with some code if it helps. But really I haven't touched much yet. I'm using all defaults so far.

Comment: updated with firebug notes too

Comment: I think I found my own answer. Using "div" instead of "li"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question. It seems that using `<ul>` and `<li>` does not generate the same behavior as using `<div>` in this plugin.

My final code looked like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        wrapperClass: 'bx-wrapper home-slider'
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="slider1">

                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="description">
                            <h3>La cuisine au style industriel</h3>
                            <div class="author dark">Marie Clairet Maison</div>

                            <p class="gray">
                                J'aime beaucoup le concept de self service pour la cuisine. 
                                J'ai vraiment l'impression d'être devant un e comptoir de self à la cantine. 
                                Le problème, c'est qu'il faut vraiment avoir de la place pour s'offrir ce genre d'installation.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="images/home-slider-placeholder.png" />
                    </div>

  <div>Slide two content</div>
  <div>Slide three content</div>
  <div>And so on...</div>
</div>
```

As far as moving the arrow controls within the slider, edit the bx_styles.css and change the locations of bx-next and bx-prev.